# Someone copied my npm and released under different name. What do I do?

Tags: node.js, npm, bsd

Someone took my npm and released a new npm with my code under a different name. It looks like he only altered a few lines. His readme file has most of my words. It's also under a BSD license.  Should I care and ask him to take it down, or leave it be?

Comment: When licensing issues come up, the generally-accepted first step is a quiet, polite, private message seeking a solution. If not at least ask the guy to acknowledge your work, then decide is it worthwhile to go for legal action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the BSD license, redistribution like that is permitted only when proper source attribution is given. So releasing a patched npm under a different name is more or less fine (though rude if they didn't even contact you regarding why it needed altering), but if they simply removed your name and info and put in theirs then it is a license violation and you should contact them and/or report it.

The BSD license asks that the author merely be compensated with recognition of his work, and to violate that is...well, a big no no. In the academic world such a thing is plagiarism and is pretty well the civil equivalent of murder - ie, to be punished in the most severe way allowable.

Is it worth your time? Well, that's up to you. If they were just unaware of their improper behavior and are willing to fix it, fine, but if done intentionally/maliciously then "may the bird of paradise fly up their nose", and may all of their favorite webpages begin using the blink tag.